# How to create a custom deserializer on spring kafka?

Tags: kotlin, spring-kafka

I've created a consumer to receive messages from a Kafka topic but I'm parsing the message manually, is there a way to parse automatically with a custom deserializer for this single topic consumer?

```
// I've tried to replace the second "String" with "MyMessage" but it didn't work
// e.g: onMessage(message: ConsumerRecord<String, MyMessage>)
fun onMessage(message: ConsumerRecord<String, String>) {
    val myMessage = try {
        jacksonObjectMapper.readValue<MyMessage>(message.value())
    } catch (ex: Exception) {
        logger.error(ex.message)
        null
    }

    myMessage?.let{ // do stuff }
}
```

The expected result is:

```
fun onMessage(message: ConsumerRecord<String, MyMessage>) {
    // do something with message.value() parameter that will be for sure a MyMessage instance.
}
```

In case of a parse error can I set a callback to handle this error?

Answer (score 0):

Yes; just implement your own and add it to the consumer configuration `value.deserializer`.

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs_value.deserializer

If you are using Spring Boot:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.integration.spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer

If configured this way, it is not managed by Spring; if you want Spring to manage it, add it to the `DefaultKafkaProducerFactory` via a constructor or setter.

Spring for Apache Kafka provides a JSON deserializer:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#json-serde